# mongoose Create And Update _ nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

my functions are working correctly now when im trying to create or updat a document with mongoose it through an error:

> Uncaught Error TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined
>       at createCategory (/home/bell/workspace/panel-screen/controllers/CategoryController.js:21:21)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)

```
const createCategory = async (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let err, category;
    console.log(req.body)
    [err, category] = await to(Category.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        lang: req.body.lang,
    }))
    if (err) return ReE422(res, err);

    return ReS(res, category)

}

module.exports.createCategory = createCategory;
```

I even reinstalled body parser.this is my body:

```
{ name: 'foo', lang: 'en' }
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't just do `try { let category = await Category.create(({ name, lang }) => ({ name, lang }))(req.body)); return ReS(res, category) } catch (e) { return Re422(res, e); }`? Or did you just not realize you could do that in native code and presumed you needed some obscure library? Speaking of "native", there is `res.json(category)` which also does that `setHeader` thing for you as well.

Comment: yeah to is a short hand for promise : to = function (promise) {
    return promise
        .then(data => {
            return [null, data];
        }).catch(err =>
            [{ message: err.message, code: err.code }]
        );
}; @NeilLunn if error comes from db it fills that. and for my response I created functions .in there I pass the json return

Comment: So what I mean by "did not realize" is what I wrote there **is shorthand** and natively so for `Promise` resolution. You seemingly read someone's blog and thought this `to` thing is something new. It's not. Modern code can be written like I did in the comment.

Comment: I dont think this syntax bother with my problem ?is it? I choose this syntax for handling my responses with less code. I didnt get it from any blog post . i read some artcles about handling better promise functions . so I thought it could be better handle them like this . cause I am not writing my responses same over and over again in every controller i wrote. sry maybe im wrong maybe this is old style or what you said is from someone else blog .but its working fine.